# What is the six page Risus rulebook?

Tags: product-identification, risus

Across various sources on the internet I have seen references to a Risus rulebook that is six pages long. The core Risus rulebook currently available is four pages, and the Risus Companion is far longer than six pages. I cannot check if this refers to an older edition of the core rulebook because I do not seem to be able to find any other edition of the core rules than the four page one. So what exactly is this six page rulebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=risus+six-page&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) netted a 6-page version of *Risus the Anything RPG*, linked [here](http://connect.ala.org/files/Risus15.pdf). It appears to be from 2001, and is labeled as version 1.53.

The later version, [here on DriveThruRPG](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/170294) is from 2013, and is 4 pages long.